# Proving a recurrence relation with induction

Tags: logic

I've been having trouble with an assignment I received with the course I am following.
The assignment in question:

Use induction to prove that when n >= 2 is an exact power of 2, the solution of
the recurrence:

```
T(n) = {2 if n = 2, 
        2T(n/2)+n if n =2^k with k > 1 }
is T(n) = nlog(n)
```

NOTE: the logarithms in the assignment have base 2.

The base case here is obvious, when n = 2, we have that 2 = 2log(2)
However, I am stuck on the step here and I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: This question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Always try the next few values if they also follow the same pattern. You know which is the next value to be considered. Then - just try to see if the statement holds for it. NOTE: the statement is to be examined only for powers of two.

Comment: @Alex, Thank you I did not even know this website existed.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Take a few minutes to explore other thematic sites of stackexchange, you might find something else relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

Step. Let us assume that the statement holds for 2^m for all m <= k and let us show it for 2^{k+1}.

Then, T(2^{k+1}) = 2T(2^k) + 2^{k+1}.

By the inductive assumption T(2^k) = 2^k*log(2^k), i.e., T(2^k) = k*2^k (since the logarithms have base 2 here).

Hence, T(2^{k+1}) = 2*k*2^k + 2^{k+1} = 2^{k+1}*(k+1), which can be written as 2^{k+1}*log(2^{k+1}), completing the proof.